# Making a particular task inside a loop as multithreaded after while reading from CSV file

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

I'm having a method for parsing CSV file and save the values into MySQL database. here I'm iterating through the file line by line, and storing it to DB. Is there any way to make use of threads for reading and writing the line parallel so that execution happens fast?

Below is the piece of code which I would like to do in a multithreaded way.

```
public String csvUpload(MultipartFile file){
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        int header = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // TO SKIP HEADER
            if(header == 0) {
                header++;  
                continue;
            }
            header++;
            //Use Comma As Separator
            String[] csvDataSet = line.split(",");
            /*
               Call a Validator Method to Validate Data.
                if no Errors then{
               mapping to Pojo
             }else{
              Mapping the errors into error-List
            }
           once the whole file is read, then 
           if error-List is empty
              call saveAll() and save data.
           else 
              save the Errors into Db.

       */

        }

    }catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "Success";
}
```

I need to do like below, using threads.so that execution happens fast.

```
thread1 --> line 1-10
thread2 --> line 11-20
```

and threads should perform the below task in parallel.

```
Call Validator Method(){
                    if no Errors then{
                   mapping to Pojo
                 }else{
                  Mapping the errors into error-List
                }
```

}

once the whole file is read, then 
                   if error-List is empty
                      call saveAll() and save data.
                   else 
                      save the Errors into Db.

any suggestions and corrections are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use two threads and a thread safe queue. The first thread reads each line from file and pushes it onto the queue. The second thread waits for items to be pushed to the queue, then pops items and sends them to the DB. This is just one approach. You should also know that introducing multi threading to a program does not, in any way, guarantee an increase in performance.

Comment: Since the processing speed of this task is most likely limited by I/O (reading from file / writing to the database), making it multi-threaded is unlikely to make it faster. If you're reading the file from a harddisk, it might even be a lot slower since multiple threads will be fighting for access to the harddisk, making the disk have to jump between parts of the file.

Comment: As a side note, you can't really read the file in parallel, because it cant now where each line begins before reaching a \n character

Comment: Using multiple threads won't necessarily increase the speed. Ideally you should profile your code to see what takes the most time. `BufferedReader` is part of Java IO. Have you considered trying Java NIO? For example, class `java.nio.MappedByteBuffer`.

Answer (score 1):

One way avoid reading line by line is using the Java 7 Files class which has a readAllLines method.
After that you can submit callable tasks to an exectuorService  to insert it into DB with multiple threads .

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path), encoding);
```